# Как сделать, чтобы при прокрутке до определенного положения происходил однократный запуск функции?

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Есть функция `scrl`, которая запускает другую функцию  (движение элемента на странице `ring`), если мы прокрутили до определенного положения. Но вот только, если мы покрутим страницу еще раз, то элемент, дойдя до конца, не остановится, а продолжит менять свое положение, то есть функция `ring` продолжает запускаться.

- как остановить выполнение функции?
- как сделать чтобы функция `ring` выполнилась однократно только в тот момент когда сработало условие?

```js
var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
  hh = parseInt($('.wrapdiv').css('height'));

function ring() {
  $('.ring').delay(500).animate({ //1
      left: 187,
    },
    800);
  $('.ring').delay(500).animate({ //2
      left: 300,
    },
    800);
  $('.ring').delay(500).animate({ //2.1
      left: 394,
    },
    800);
  $('.ring').animate({ //3
      left: 481,
      top: 100,
    },
    800);
};


function scrl() {
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (top > ((h + hh) / 2)) {
    ring();
  }
  
  
  //внутри этой функции может быть куча дургих мне нужно остановить только функцию ring()
};



function myfoo() {
  $('.firstdiv').css('height', h);
};
$(window).scroll(scrl);
$(window).resize(myfoo);
$(document).ready(myfoo);
```

```css
.parentring {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1050px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.ring {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #DCDCDC;
  border: 4px solid #F1F1F1;
  left: 87px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #006492, inset 0 0 7px #153F53;
}
.wrapdiv {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 244px;
  background: #CE93D8;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
.firstdiv {
  background: #FFB74D;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="firstdiv"></div>
<div class="wrapdiv">Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что укрепление и развитие структуры влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации систем массового участия. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности
  обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании новых предложений. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также новая модель организационной деятельности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки систем массового участия.
 зации соответствующий условий активизации. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также укрепление и развитие структуры позволяет оценить значение новых предложений. Равным образом укрепление и развитие структуры требуют
  от нас анализа системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям. С другой стороны дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям. Не следует,
  однако забывать, что сложившаяся структура организации позволяет оценить значение дальнейших направлений развития. Товарищи! консультация с широким активом позволяет оценить значение позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Равным
  образом рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет оценить значение системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.

</div>
<div class="parentring">
  <div class="ring"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: событие `scroll` возникает на каждый шаг прокрутки

Comment: потому я и написал его чтобы узнать отступ от верха, чтобы запустить функцию в нужный момент, но она запускается постоянно, ведь срабатывает скролл. а вопрос выше)

Comment: так не запускайте ее второй раз

Comment: то есть когда я докручу до нужно положения мне мышку выдернуть??

Comment: вопрос в том, как запустить функцию однократно при прокрутке до определенного положения.

Comment: например флаг поставить и проверять его

Comment: что то вроде i=0 i++? хоть подскажите, как должно выглядеть условие, которое остановит функцию, если мое предположение верно.

Comment: да вроде бы родил)))

Answer (score 1):

Кажется вот этого достаточно))

```js
var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
  hh = parseInt($('.wrapdiv').css('height'));
i=0; 
function ring() {
if(i<1){
  $('.ring').delay(500).animate({ //1
      left: 187,
    },
    800);
  $('.ring').delay(500).animate({ //2
      left: 300,
    },
    800);
  $('.ring').delay(500).animate({ //2.1
      left: 394,
    },
    800);
  $('.ring').animate({ //3
      left: 481,
      top: 100,
    },
    800);
  }
return i++;
};


function scrl() {
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (top > ((h + hh) / 2)) {
    ring();
  }
  
  
  //внутри этой функции может быть куча дургих мне нужно остановить только функцию ring()
};



function myfoo() {
  $('.firstdiv').css('height', h);
};
$(window).scroll(scrl);
$(window).resize(myfoo);
$(document).ready(myfoo);
```

```css
.parentring {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1050px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.ring {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #DCDCDC;
  border: 4px solid #F1F1F1;
  left: 87px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #006492, inset 0 0 7px #153F53;
}
.wrapdiv {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 244px;
  background: #CE93D8;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
.firstdiv {
  background: #FFB74D;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="firstdiv"></div>
<div class="wrapdiv">Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что укрепление и развитие структуры влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации систем массового участия. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности
  обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании новых предложений. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также новая модель организационной деятельности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки систем массового участия.
 зации соответствующий условий активизации. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также укрепление и развитие структуры позволяет оценить значение новых предложений. Равным образом укрепление и развитие структуры требуют
  от нас анализа системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям. С другой стороны дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям. Не следует,
  однако забывать, что сложившаяся структура организации позволяет оценить значение дальнейших направлений развития. Товарищи! консультация с широким активом позволяет оценить значение позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Равным
  образом рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет оценить значение системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.

</div>
<div class="parentring">
  <div class="ring"></div>
</div>
```